# AT&T syntax: any difference between inl (%dx),%eax and inl %dx,%eax?

Tags: gcc, x86, inline-assembly, att

I have this code:

```
__asm__ __volatile__ ("inl (%%dx), %%eax"
                         : "=a" (result), "=b" (ebxReg)
                         : ...
                           "d"  (IO_PORT),
                           "b"  (0)
                         : "memory");
```

1. What is the difference between `inl %%dx` and `inl (%%dx)`? My guess is its the same (only for `inl` instructions) but wanted to make sure
2. Will `ebx` be set to 0 **BEFORE** the `inl` instruction will be executed?

Comment: 1) There is no difference. It was a decision by those who created x86 AT&T syntax to support parentheses around the port number register. Probably because a port in IO space is similar in nature to a memory address (but not a memory address).Someone probably thought access to IO space and and memory should allow for consistent use of parentheses. Personally I think it makes it confusing for new people maintaining a code base as they may have to think about it.

Comment: 2) EBX will be set to 0 before your assembly template executes. When finished the value in _EBX_ will be transferred to the variable `ebxReg`

Comment: You don't show all your code so I assume your template actually modifies the _EBX_ register but you don't show that code. I recommend against doing more in assembly than is needed.  Write a function that gets a 32-bit value of a port using inline assembly but do other work in _C_. Only use inline assembly when needed and try to write as much in _C_ as possible.

Comment: The comment regarding parentheses applies to `inl` `inb` and `inw` . It is not specific to `inl`